# Is it correct to edit something in already edit mode?

Tags: usability

If i want to change size of matrix or edit matrix then i can edit values,its descriptions and output of those values so i am displaying same screen in edit mode but the problem is how should i add the description for those values.

I have screen which has matrix calculation.The matrix screen is in the edit mode. User can edit values but user also want to add more information for those values.so i am clicking edit icon on the screen which is already in the edit mode.
Is it correct way? 
If no then what will be the solution for that screen

[image]

Comment: In your example, does "editing a description" mean modifying the X1-X5, Y1-Y5 labels?

Comment: edit means to add more description like tool tip for those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As only the edit icon is causing confusion, you could replace it with something more contextual. On hover/click of this icon, a callout could be shown with an option to view as well as edit the text.

Your layout should then look something like below.

[image]

You can either keep or remove the "Cancel" and "Done" buttons depending on whether you have a global level save or not.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to minimize user confusion.
And with this approach all the confusion happends when you click global **"Cancel"**

Imagine scenario:

1. You entered edit mode
2. You dive deeper into description edit
3. You enter new description and hit "OK" / "Save"
4. You click global "Cancel" meaning "Exit without changes"

Now what would happen to new description entered on step 3?
Will it be reverted back to previous value or be preserved.

This is why people usually avoid nested edits.
However if you somehow make user know what whould happen, it is totally fine.